# what is wrong with subscript of string here in C++

Tags: c++, string, subscript

This code should print "something here", but it actually print wrong

```
void test(){
    string str = "";
    int count = 0;
    if (count > str.length() - 1){
        cout << "something here" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "wrong" << endl;
}
```

But, if I change a little as below, it will print "something here"

```
void test_2(){
    string str = "";
    int count = 0;
    int last_index = str.length() - 1;
    if (count > last_index){      // change to last_index
        cout << "something here" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "wrong" << endl;
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Turn on/up your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string::length` returns a `size_t` which is `unsigned int`.

If it returns 0, and you subtract 1, it will [underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

The reason it works in your second case is that since you say

```
int last_index = str.length() - 1;
```

The `size_t` is converted to `int` during the subtraction and assignment.

Comment: It's converted to `int` *after* the subtraction, in an implementation-defined manner that happens to yield `-1`. Also, `size_t` isn't likely to be `unsigned int` on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Interesting. So based on the order of precedence, is it technically specified if the conversion should be performed first?

Comment: The subtraction will promote both to the unsigned integer type that is `size_t` (depending on the platform, this can be `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`), the result is converted to an `int` in an implementation-defined manner (since it cannot be represented in `int`'s range) and used to initialize `last_index`.